# How to find which code is changing the settings of the Decimal context in a long-running process?

Tags: python, django

After scratching my head for days over a bizarre and intermittent problem in a Django app I'm responsible for, I eventually determined that the problem was that the configuration of the default Decimal context (the precision setting, in particular) is being altered without being altered back. I've worked around this, but still haven't determined where or why it's happening. It doesn't seem to be occurring in my code, so I suspect that it must be some 3rd-party package or other, and I'd like to determine which one so I can file a report with the vendor.

So, what are some techniques I could use to track down the code (or at least the package, but the more granular the better) that's modifying the settings of the Decimal context, without spending a ton of time auditing source code?

Python 3.8.5, Django 4.1.

Comment: Edit the source code where the precision set method is and log the stack trace to a file. Assuming there is a set method.

Comment: @BrendanOtherwhyz I had looked into that before posting, but `decimal` is a C module. Specifically, a C module with a pure-Python fallback. I'll look into whether I can force it to use the Python version.

Comment: An interesting method I saw while skimming the python fallback as you say, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/_pydecimal.py, was localcontext. It seemed relevant to managing precision from local scope. I would also grep for /\.prec\s*=/ in the packages you're using as that would be where a change could be happening.

Comment: It's unspecific. You need to research more and ask a specific question with a [mre]. Anyway here's my opinion. What about monkey-patching the ```decimal.getcontext()``` and ```decimal.setcontext()```? (It may use a custom ```Context``` which overrides the original ```__setattr__```.)

Comment: @BrendanOtherwhyz localcontext is actually one of the methods I used to work around the issue. I'm still holding out hope of finding a way to make your stack trace suggestion work before I start grepping through source code. Thanks for you interest in helping me with this!

Comment: @relent95 I wracked my brain to come up with a way to make a "minimum reproducible example" that would add context but couldn't see a way to do it concisely and meaningfully. Just tried monkeypatching a wrapper around `decimal.setcontext` and `decimal.getcontext` and the initial results are looking promising, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then, what about editing the question so that it is asking how to find the problematic module by monkeypatching the ```decimal``` module? And you can answer your own question.